# compare (T, T) in Comparator cannot be applied to (T, T)

Tags: java, class, generics, intellij-idea, comparator

Intellij idea is giving me this error: "compare (T, T) in Comparator cannot be applied to (T, T)" for the follow code:

```
public class LCCS<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private Comparator<T> comparator;

    public LCCS(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }


    /**
     * Loops the two given lists for finding the longest subequence
     *
     * @param list1 first list.
     * @param list2 second list.
     * @param <T>   list item type.
     * @return LCCS and the sublist indices of the subsequence in list1 and list2.
     */
    private <T> Subsequence<T> getLongestSubsequence(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
        Subsequence<T> output = null;
        for (int indexList1 = 0; indexList1 < list1.size(); indexList1++)
            for (int indexList2 = 0; indexList2 < list2.size(); indexList2++)
                if (comparator.compare((T)list1.get(indexList1), (T)list2.get(indexList2)) //Here comes the error
        output = inspectsubsequence(list1, list2, indexList1, indexList2, output);
        return output;
    }
}
```

I've already changed the parametrized type to T and it still shows me the message but instead of capture just T. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Its just a part of the class haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two different generic type parameters named T - one at the class level and the other at the `getLongestSubsequence` method. The two are not related, even though they have the same name. Therefore `comparator.compare` doesn't accept the same type of arguments as the element type of the lists passed to the `getLongestSubsequence` method.

As the class is currently written, you can, for example, create an instance of `LCCS<String>` and then call the `getLongestSubsequence` method with two `List<Integer>` arguments. `comparator.compare()` would then expect two `String`s, while your code would pass to it two `Integer`s. That's why your code doesn't pass compilation.

Just remove `<T>` from the declaration of `getLongestSubsequence`, which will cause it to use the class level `T`.

Comment: Why do I need to extends <T extends Comparable<T>>? Is the extension realy needed?

Comment: @CeesMandjes Perhaps you don't need it. I can't tell without seeing your full code. Having the `extends Comparable<T>` type bound allows you to call `compareTo(T)` on instances of T inside your class. For example, if `comparator` is null, you can call `list1.get(indexList1).compareTo(list2.get(indexList2))` instead of `comparator.compare(list1.get(indexList1), list2.get(indexList2))`.

Answer (score 4):

The type parameter `T` at **classlevel** is defined here:

```
public class LCCS<T extends Comparable<T>> {
```

Later, this code defines another type parameter with name `T` for the scope of the **method**; it **shadows** the classlevel declaration:

```
private <T> Subsequence<T> getLongestSubsequence(...
```

Change this code. Let the method **resuse** the classlevel's type parameter `T`:

```
private Subsequence<T> getLongestSubsequence(...
```

Comment: Why do I need to extends <T extends Comparable<T>>? Is the extension realy needed?